# It is showing me a TypeError that list is not callable [python]

Tags: python, typeerror

when i run this code it is showing me an error that the array list is not callable but why?

````
array= [2,5,7,5,7,5,4,4]

for x in range(0,len(array)):
    total = total + array(x)

print("total is equals to = {}".format(total))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array(x)` needs to be `array[x]`

```
 total = total + array[x]
```

If you want to access the element of the array you need use `[]` notation, not `()`.